# Upgraded to Express 4 and now body parser is not working. Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I just upgraded from express 3 to 4 and now my body parser is not working. My code looks like below.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const winston = require('winston');
const UserModel = require('../models').User;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // prints { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }
    winston.debug(req.body); // prints nothing

      const username = req.body.username;
      const password = req.body.password;

      var user = await UserModel.findOne({
        where: {
            user_name: req.body.username
        }
    })
});
```

Also UserModel.findOne fails because req.body.username not working.This use to work fine in express 4.

"express": "~4.17.1"
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",

Answer (score 1):

[For express v4.16.0](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) they bring back `express.json()` so you can remove bodyParser and try this:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) the Express route-specific example.
Try this way:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const winston = require('winston');
const UserModel = require('../models').User;

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});

app.post('/login', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body); // prints { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }
    winston.debug(req.body); // prints nothing

      const username = req.body.username;
      const password = req.body.password;

      var user = await UserModel.findOne({
        where: {
            user_name: req.body.username
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gabor. That didnt work either. Found some more information.
 console.log('req.body.username); // prints admin
 logger.debug(req.body.username); // prints nothing
 logger.debug(typeof req.body); // prints Object
 logger.debug(typeof req.body.username); // prints String
 logger.debug(`${req.body.username}`); // prints admin